# Create shapefile using textfile in QGIS

Tags: gis, shapefile, qgis

I have a shapefile in QGIS which has polygons in it . There are several other attributes for each feature .

I want to add another attribute to each feature . The value for this attribute is available to me in a text file . How do i add this column programatically to the existing shapefile's attribute table .

It is not feasible to do it manually as i will have to change the value of that attribute quite often and the number of features are in thousands.

I am open to suggestions to use other GIS software if that fits my requirements.

Comment: Does the shapefile have an attribute that can be linked to another attribute in the textfile? If so, you can try to use joins, see here: http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_csv.php

Comment: I can manually add a serial number to each feature in the shape-file and then put the same serial number in the text file as well.